# Mysql - List duplicate values grouped by category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

t_contacts

```
| id | gid | email            | desc |
+----+-----+------------------+------+
|  1 |  1  | foo@email.com    |      |
|  2 |  1  | bar@email.com    |      |
|  3 |  1  | foo@email.com    |  c   |
|  4 |  1  | foo@email.com    |  c   |
|  5 |  2  | foo@email.com    |  a   |
|  6 |  2  | bar@email.com    |      |
|  7 |  2  | doe@email.com    |  x   |
|  8 |  2  | doe@email.com    |  x   |
```

I would like to list all the equal email values with the same gid (grouped gid?) in order to obtain this result

```
| id | gid | email            | desc |
+----+-----+------------------+------+
|  1 |  1  | foo@email.com    |      |
|  3 |  1  | foo@email.com    |  c   |
|  4 |  1  | foo@email.com    |  c   |
|  5 |  2  | foo@email.com    |  a   |
|  7 |  2  | doe@email.com    |  x   |
|  8 |  2  | doe@email.com    |  x   |
```

I tried to do this, but I can't find duplicate records broken down by groups.

```
SELECT cid, gidid, email
FROM t_contacts
WHERE email IN (
  SELECT email FROM t_contacts GROUP BY email HAVING count(email) > 1
)
ORDER BY email
```

How could I do it?
Thank you

Comment: Why the record `id=5` is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task is "Select all records which have the same `(email, gid)` pair valies", then

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t_contacts t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM t_contacts t2
               WHERE t1.email = t2.email
                 AND t1.gid = t2.gid
                 AND t1.id != t2.id )
```

---

It the task is "Select all records with `email`, for which there exists 2 records with the same `gid`", then look for [@D-Shih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5176071/d-shih)'s solution.

Comment: @PaoloRossi I'm confused. This returns a different result from what was requested - and what's wrong with JOINs?

Comment: @Strawberry There are 2 variants. 1 - misprint in desured result, 2 - the inaccuracy in formulation of the goal. If my solution is accepted then either we have variant 1, or the OP did not pay attention to the absence of the entry `id=5`.

Comment: @Akina It would be nice to know; that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `JOIN` with a subquery.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE t_contacts(
   id int,
   gid int, 
  email varchar(500),
   `desc` varchar(5)
);


INSERT INTO t_contacts VALUES (1 ,1 ,'foo@email.com',' ');
INSERT INTO t_contacts VALUES (2 ,1 ,'bar@email.com',' ');
INSERT INTO t_contacts VALUES (3 ,1 ,'foo@email.com','c');
INSERT INTO t_contacts VALUES (4 ,1 ,'foo@email.com','c');
INSERT INTO t_contacts VALUES (5 ,2 ,'foo@email.com','a');
INSERT INTO t_contacts VALUES (6 ,2 ,'bar@email.com',' ');
INSERT INTO t_contacts VALUES (7 ,2 ,'doe@email.com','x');
INSERT INTO t_contacts VALUES (8 ,2 ,'doe@email.com','x');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t_contacts t1 JOIN (
    SELECT email
    FROM t_contacts 
    GROUP BY email,gid
    HAVING count(email) > 1
) t2 on t1.email = t2.email 
ORDER BY t1.id;

| id  | gid | email         | desc |
| --- | --- | ------------- | ---- |
| 1   | 1   | foo@email.com |      |
| 3   | 1   | foo@email.com | c    |
| 4   | 1   | foo@email.com | c    |
| 5   | 2   | foo@email.com | a    |
| 7   | 2   | doe@email.com | x    |
| 8   | 2   | doe@email.com | x    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e8WpkNhdS6BgQ3DaYhMiyv/0)